# ValueConverter for IsChecked property of WPF Toggle Button

Tags: wpf, data-binding, ivalueconverter

I'm trying to write a Value converter to use to bind the Boolean IsChecked property of a WPF ToggleButton to a non Boolean value (which happens to be a double) in my model. The convert function I've written looks like this:

```
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object paramter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culutre)
        {
          if (targetType != typeof(Boolean))
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Target type should be Boolean");

          var input = double.Parse(value.ToString());

          return (input==0.0) ? false: true;
        }
```

The problem is that when the funcion is invoked, the targetType is not what I expect - it's

```
            "System.Nullable`1[[System.Boolean, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]"
```

Rather than System.Boolean. Is this expected? I've written other converters with no hassle in the past.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, since a ToggleButton (think of a checkbox) can be in three states: Checked, Unchecked and Neither (checkbox would be greyed out).

The [MSDN library states](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms612601.aspx):

```
ToggleButton Class
Base class for controls that can switch states, such as CheckBox.
```

and [for IsChecked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton.ischecked.aspx):

```
Property Value
Type: System.Nullable<Boolean>
true if the ToggleButton is checked; false if the ToggleButton is unchecked; otherwise null. The default is false.
```

So if you cast to a `bool?` or Nullable, you can easily get the value with `.HasValue` and `.Value`.

Comment: +1 for mentioning .HasValue.  When I first started using nullable types, I got in trouble by accesssing Value without checking HasValue. @_@

Answer (score 3):

This is as expected; [`IsChecked`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton.ischecked.aspx) is a `bool?`, not a `bool`. Change your first line to this:

```
if (targetType != typeof(bool?))
```

Answer (score 3):

[IsChecked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton.ischecked.aspx) is a nullable boolean. So instead of `Boolean`, check for `bool?`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, IsChecked is a 'nullable' boolean... meaning it could be true, false, or null.  It's pretty rare to have a toggle button with a null value here but more common on some of the subclasses like CheckBox.